# Is $e^{x}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(x)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory, power-series

We have $$e^{x}= \sum \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$ as a power series expansion. We can see that such a power series has radius of convergence infinity and as a result $e^x$ is defined over the whole complex plane. But how do we see that such a power series is algebraic/not algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(x)$?

In general, if we have a formal power series (coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$)   with radius of convergence, say $R$, then what are the possible ways to proceed, in order to determine if that is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(x)$ or not?

Comment: If $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb F$ then $e^x$ is trancendental over $\mathbb F$

Comment: I am not sure if the radius of convergence matters when you are considering *formal* power series.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\exp(x)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(x)$. Then we can suppose that we have a non trivial relation (the $P_j$ are in $\mathbb{C}[x]$):
$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^s P_j(x)\exp(jx)=0$ for all $x$ (in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{C}$, this is the same thing). In addition, we can suppose that $P_0(x)P_s(x)$ is not zero, and that the integer $s$ is minimal, and also that ${\rm Max}{\rm degree}(P_j)$ is minimal. Note also we cannot have all $P_j$ constants, as $Q(\exp(x))=0$ for all $x$ for a (not zero) polynomial $Q\in \mathbb{C}[y]$ is impossible.

Hint for solution A): Use the fact that $P_j(x)\exp(jx)\to 0$ if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\to -\infty$, for $j\geq 1$.

Hint for solution B): Replace $x$ by $x+2in\pi$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, show that for fixed $x$ the polynomial in $y$ $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^s P_j(x+y)\exp(jx) $ is zero, and differentiate it with respect to $y$.